# Android: How to get rid of EditText with null value using loop

Tags: android, arrays, list, loops, android-edittext

First of all, here is my code:

```
startRandomizing.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {

         ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
             int idList[] = new int[]{R.id.textBox1,R.id.textBox2,R.id.textBox3,
                                      R.id.textBox4,R.id.textBox5,R.id.textBox6};

             for(int id : idList){
                 if (findViewById(id) != null) {
                     values.add(((EditText) findViewById(id)).getText().toString());
                     }
             }


     String[] myItems = values.toArray(new String[values.size()]);
```

What I want to do is get rid of all the null values so that the length (myItems.length) of the array will depend on the value inside the text boxes 1 - 6.

(E.x - I have a string "Hello" in textBox1 and "World" in textBox2, and the rest empty. My desired output for myItems.length should be 2 since the remaining textBoxes do not have a value.)

This code outputs 6 (counts all the text boxes). Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Sounds like you don't want to add the values if the value is null: `if(theEditText.getText().toString() != null) values.add(theEditText.getText().toString());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code in the for loop as follows:

```
String s = ((EditText) findViewById(id)).getText().toString();
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(s)){
    values.add(s);
}
```

Comment: My 30 minute problem, answered after 2 minutes of posting. Thank you. But I do have a problem though, I seem to not be able to bring myItems.length out (the app crashes) unless I convert it to String (String example = myItems.length + "";)

Comment: What do you mean by `I seem to not be able to bring myItems.length out`? Do you mean you trying to print it? If that is the case, then Log and System prints both expect only string as the output. You should change your length (which is an `int`) to a `String` using `String.valueOf(values.size())`.

Comment: Yes I am indeed trying to print it. I need it to be an 'int' since I have to multiply the length with a random number. (I'm trying to make an app that randomizes user input).

Comment: Since the print functions takes in only `String` as the input, you should do something like `String.valueOf(values.size())`.

Comment: Your first comment went over my head. I understand now, thank you!